# Concatenate columns in select query and add comma if value isn't null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, null

I have on main table and 10 left joins with second table:

```
SELECT a.*, f1.Name + ',' + f2.Name + ',' ...
[dbo].[tblStep] a (nolock)
left join OPStep_Flag (nolock) sf1  ON sf1.StepId = a.StepId
left join OPFlag f1 (nolock) ON f1.Id = sf1.FlagId AND f1.Id = 1
left join OPStep_Flag sf2 (nolock) ON sf2.StepId = a.StepId
left join OPFlag f2 (nolock) ON f2.Id = sf2.FlagId AND f2.Id = 3
left join ...
```

And now the problem is with commas, because if `f1.Name` will be null in result I will get ',aaa'.

How to avoid print commas if any of flag is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting SQL Server 2017, you can use [`concat_ws()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> `CONCAT_WS` ignores null values during concatenation, and does not add the separator between null values. Therefore, `CONCAT_WS` can cleanly handle concatenation of strings that might have "blank" values

```
concat_ws(',', f1.Name, f2.Name, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

If 2012-2016... `Concat()` will treat `NULL` values as empty strings

```
stuff( concat( ','+f1.Name , ','+f2.Name , ','+f3.Name ) ,1,1,'')
```

So for example, notice the middle value will be null

```
Select stuff(concat( ','+'John' , ','+null , ','+'Smith' ),1,1,'')
```

Returns

```
John,Smith
```

Comment: This depends on the setting of parameter CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL. If OFF then NULLs will be concatenated as empty strings. This is a deprecated option however.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths Very true, but not the default setting  :)

Comment: what is case when f1.Name is null and f2.Name isn't null, we have result: ,Ben (with comma at the begin)

Comment: @Robert easy fix repeat the pattern for f1 and wrap the whole thing in a stuff()

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it down at the plant

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, L.COLUMN1) + ',' AS [data()]
FROM TABLE1 l 
FOR XML PATH('')